# How to write average of a function?

Tags: symbols

Just do not know how to write the average of a function. The symbol look like a integral sign with a short bar in the middle. It means integral of a function over a ball divide by the measure of the ball, and let the radius of the ball goes to 0+.

Comment: Have a look to see if the solution given here answers your question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46967/r-integral-symbol-for-my-notes

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). If the above link does not solve your issue, please update the question with more details.

Comment: I think a better answer is [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol). I tried Detexify and think you might mean \fint

Comment: @DJP: Hmm, no, I think the bar shouldn't be slanted. By the way, also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60769) which asks for the same was closed as duplicate of "How to look up a symbol" (probably due to the OP saying "thank you"). The mother of those questions seems to be [Average integral symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/759).