# Writing limits of integration

Tags: math-operators

I'm not sure exactly what it's called, but I would like to draw the line after an integral has been "solved," showing limits of integration, like so:

[image]

There is a line with a 9 above and 1 below.

Comment: This could help with adjustments: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46968/14757 To insert limits, use `_0^9`

Comment: Try $\left. abc \right|^9_1$

Comment: I would define a command `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\eval.\rbrack` and use `\eval{..}_{1}^{9}`.

Comment: Typesetting aside, I would not use this vertical line notation if the expression in front of it involves additive terms. Better choose square brackets, and decorate the closing `]` with the limits `_1^9`. For instance you might have `[2+x]_1^9=8`. In your notation, this might be misread as `2+[x]_1^9=10`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that what you are looking for is:

[image]

You can do this quite nicely with `\Biggr|`:

```
\[
  2x + \frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{1}{x}\Biggr|_{1}^{9}
\]
```

Personally, I prefer this approach. As you can see the line extends slightly above and below the the expression to its left. It also saves you having to have a preceding `\left.`

Use `\Biggr|` where you have a "tall" expression (e.g. with fractions, like here) and you can just use `\Bigr|` for "short" ones, e.g.:

```
\[
  y \cdot x(y)\Bigr|_{y_{1}}^{y_{2}}
\]
```

Produces:

[image]

You can also use `\Bigl|` for a lone vertical line to the left, or you can pair them if ever you wish to do so.

This `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` format can be used with other types of bracket, too, e.g. `\Bigr]`

As Benjamin McKay points out in the comments, you could also use:

```
\[
  \left. 2x + \frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}} + \frac{1}{x}\right|_{1}^{9}
\]
```

This is an excellent solution if you want your vertical line to be the same height as the preceding expression. Generally `\left(` and `\right)` should scale the brackets so that they are the same height as what they enclose. With `\Bigl(` & `\Bigr)` and `\Biggl(` & `\Biggr)` you are using brackets of a fixed height. A `\right` must always be paired with a `\left`, while `\Bigr|` does not have this problem. This is why you must use `\left.` and `\right|`. If you don't want a left hand bracket, you must have `\left.` (and vice versa if you don't want a right hand bracket).

Answer (score 8):

This solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\int^b_a f(x)dx=\left. F(x) \right]^b_a=F(b)-F(a)
\]

\[
\int^b_a f(x)dx=\left. \frac{F(x)}{1} \right]^b_a=F(b)-F(a)
\]

\[
\int^b_a f(x)dx=\left. \frac{\frac{F(x)}{1}}{270-269} \right]^b_a=F(b)-F(a)
\]

\end{document}
```

adjusts properly, as the height and width of the content between `\left.` and `\right]^b_a` change. The output:

[image: screenshot of output pdf]

**Addendum:** At the same way, if one replaces the three occurrences of `\right]^b_a` with `\right|^b_a` in the code above, the same delimiter satisfies again each of the three cases:

[image: screenshot of output pdf 2]

---

In my opinion, `\Bigr|` (compared to `\right|`) has the "advantage" that it doesn't need any `\left.` before, but it also has two minor "disadvantages".

1) It requires `\usepackage{amsmath}` in the preamble (but this is not the problem, since anybody writing a paper with such contents would use this package anyway, I guess).

2) One must be chosen case by case among `\bigr|`, `\Bigr|`, `\biggr|`, `\Biggr|` (see [4.14.1 at page 15](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)) and this choice is not always enough: the code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\int^b_a f(x)dx=
\frac{F(x)}{\frac{\binom{n}{n}}{\binom{k}{k}}} \Biggr|^b_a=
F(b)-F(a)
\]

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: screenshot of output pdf 3]

On the other hand, in case of such height or more, the use of `\left.`/`\right|` instead is not trivial too (for my level of experience) and should be further tested.

Comment: ] is not used to indicate the evaluation of an integral.

Comment: @user69453: I don't think so, as I've seen it used for this purpose several times before. The text of this question is an example, that indeed didn't surprise me. If you like, \right| should make it, also.

Comment: The impression I got from 'I would like to draw the line after an integral has been "solved,"' was that the original poster desired a vertical line, but had been unable to produce one for their example, and so had substituted a ]. That's why I answered the question the way I did. However, this answer is a very good answer to the question as posed and a perfectly plausible interpretation of it.

Comment: @user69453: I've edited my answer, even if I focused more on `\right` vs. `\Bigr`, rather than `]` vs. `|`. Have a check ;)

Comment: I'll remove my downvote :)