# Writing an alpha integral

Tags: integral

How can I change this integral `$$\oint_V f(s) \,ds$$` to display alpha instead of `o`?
[image]

I tried to write alpha instead of `o`, but it did not work.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where is such integral used?

Comment: I found it in this paper: https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1342&context=rhumj

Answer (score 12):

This is more or less taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46968). All I did was to change `R` to `\alpha` and adjust the kerning.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\alphaint}{\mathop{\mathrlap{\pushalpha}}\!\int}
\newcommand{\pushalpha}{\mathchoice
  {\mkern4mu \alpha}
  {\mkern2mu\scriptstyle \alpha}
  {\mkern1.5mu\scriptscriptstyle \alpha}
  {\mkern1mu\scriptscriptstyle \alpha}
}
\begin{document}
\[
\left|\alphaint_a^b f\right|\textstyle\left|\alphaint_a^b f\right|_{\left|\alphaint_a^b f\right|}
\]
\[\alphaint\limits_a^b f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

What might be more useful than this particular adaptation could be the way to find related posts: all I did was to do a Google picture search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com oint customize` and once the pic with the `R` in the integral shows up one can guess that it should be possible to replace the `R` by whatever. The danger, though, of this approach is that we keep on copying existing solutions and decrease the chances of having independent takes on problems. Yet at least I link to the more original post.

Answer (score 0):

Into your document I have seen only the symbol `\int` over `\alpha` only into a formula. Here there is my minimal proposal. It is works :-). If `\alpha` seems too big for you, you can precede the command `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle` style before of `\alpha`: for example

```
\newcommand{\intalpha}{\makebox[0pt][c]{$\displaystyle\int$}\mkern-5mu\scriptstyle\alpha\,}
```

to obtain a small o smaller `\alpha` symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\newcommand{\intalpha}{\makebox[0pt][c]{$\displaystyle\int$}\mkern-5mu\alpha\,}
\newcommand{\intalphae}{\makebox[0pt][c]{$\displaystyle\int_a^b$}\mkern-8mu\alpha\,}

\begin{document}
\[\intalpha f(t)dt=\frac{e_0 ba}{\alpha}\]
\[\intalphae f(t)dt=\frac{e_0 ba}{\alpha}\]

\end{document}
```